# how to select every nth line and swap every consecutive lines up to next mth line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have some large text files containing data like below:

```
    2.086
    0.019
    2.181
    0.004
    2.308
    0.005
    2.165
    0.023
    2.113
    0.004
    2.022
    0.005
    0.013
    0.033
    0.005
    0.026
    0.009
    0.037
```

I would like select every 13th line and swap the consecutive lines with one another up to the 18th line. The required output should be like below:

```
    2.086
    0.019
    2.181
    0.004
    2.308
    0.005
    2.165
    0.023
    2.113
    0.004
    2.022
    0.005
    0.033
    0.013
    0.026
    0.005
    0.037
    0.009
```

I was trying to construct a suitable regex for this operation but not sure how to start with selecting every 13th to 18th line !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: After discussion in comments and in chat, here is the solution first. The explanation follows.

Search: `(([^\n]*\n){12})((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))`

Replace: `\1\4\3\6\5\8\7`

**Explanation**

Here the general recipe for selecting 5 lines:

```
(?:[^\n]*\n){5}
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/aJ4vQ2)

The `[^\n]*\n` selects any number of non-newline characters, followed by a newline character. We do that 5 times. You can add anchors, lookarounds and so on to do more.

For instance, this regex swaps the first 3 lines with the next 5:

```
\A((?:[^\n]*\n){3})((?:[^\n]*\n){5})
```

The key to understand here is that groups of lines are captured to Groups 1 and 2. This is done by enclosing each expression in capturing parentheses. Later, in the replacement, as the demo shows, these groups can be referenced by their number like so: `\1` for Group 1, and so on.

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lV1eF9)

You want to target the 13th line? Match 12, then 1. You want to do something with further lines? Add lines, and switch the capture groups around as needed.

```
\A((?:[^\n]*\n){12})((?:[^\n]*\n))((?:[^\n]*\n){2})
```

In this example, the first group of parentheses captures 12 lines, the next captures the 13th line, the next captures the following two lines. You can switch the 13th and the following two lines by rearranging the groups in the replacement: `\1\3\2`

You want to do this multiple times in a file? Don't anchor. Here is a [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hT5kQ5) that swaps every 5th line with lines 6 and 7.

Just adjust to your needs.

**EDIT**

Based on your comments, this should do exactly what you need.

Search: `((?:[^\n]*\n){12})((?:[^\n]*\n))((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))((?2))`

Replace: `\1\3\2\5\4\7\6`

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/hT5kQ5)

Same idea. The `((?2))` is a way to avoid repeating the same regex over and over (the second group of capturing parentheses, which captures one line). `(?2)` says "repeat the expression in Group 2", and the extra parentheses put these expressions into groups 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.

Comment: Nice answer !! But how can repeat this process (swapping two lines) up to the 18th line then start again?
I'm using the below regex
((?:[^\n]*\n){12})((?:[^\n]*\n))((?:[^\n]*\n))

http://regex101.com/r/hT5kQ5

Comment: @jmkam On the demo link you sent, change the numbers between brackets. But I don't understand your specs exactly: what do you mean by `swapping two lines up to the 18th line then repeat`. Do you mean switch 14 with 13, 16 with 15, 18 with 17?

Comment: Yes, I've exactly meant that -- switch 14 with 13, 16 with 15, 18 with 17

Comment: @jmkam Like this http://regex101.com/r/hJ5vY0 I'll add it at the top of the answer

Comment: @jmkam Added the explanation to that at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: @jmkam next you may want to read [All About Capture](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52726/discussion-between-jmkam-and-zx81)